DFW International airport air traffic control
While listening to DFW air traffic control I hear pilots referring to Inwood and g bush when approaching the airport. What are these?

Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/what-is-the-difference-between-a-fix-a-waypoint-and-an-intersection/

Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17574/how-are-fixes-used-during-an-approach/

Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16171/what-is-a-navigational-fix-where-can-i-get-navigational-fixes-for-a-local-airpo

INWOD and GBUSH are RNAV fix points used for navigation. These two specific points are located on the ILS approach to runway 17L, on the extended centreline at 8.5 nautical miles (NM) and 5.4NM from the threshold respectively.
The names represent certain points in space defined by GNSS coordinates. Such 5-letter named points exists worldwide. The reason they exist is to make it easier for air traffic control and pilots to communicate, as they can just say a 5-letter word instead of having to spell out the GNSS coordinate (which would be a format like N43°38'19.39" W116°14'28.86"). For example, ATC might instruct pilots to "fly direct to GBUSH". It also makes it easier for pilots to input the position into the flight management system, as, again, they can just type in the 5 letters rather than typing in the coordinates.
The points do not correspond to any physical feature on the ground. They are simply virtual points defined by GNSS coordinates.
Below the approach plate for ILS 17L at KDFW where you can see INWOD and GBUSH depicted.

Source
